# Spring JDBC "IF NOT EXIST INSERT" Primary key constraint violation

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, sql-server-2012

I have a MSSQL database and a Java Spring application which uses Spring's Transaction Management.

I have a query of "IF NOT EXIT, INSERT .." which is ran from multiple threads.
For some reason I get a primary key constraint violation, even through I check for existence before writing, all happens inside a transaction.

I wanted to know what is the reason for that, and how to prevent it.

The query:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT docId FROM documentStatus WHERE docId='abc') 
BEGIN INSERT INTO documentStatus
        VALUES ('abc',1,0,NULL) 
END
ELSE
 BEGIN 
    UPDATE documentStatus SET documentStatus.count=documentStatus.count+1 
        WHERE docId ='abc'
  END;
```

DDL for documentStatus

```
CREATE TABLE Dss.dbo.docStatus 
    (
        docId  NVARCHAR(256),
        count INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
        error INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        errorMsg NVARCHAR(1024) DEFAULT NULL,

        CONSTRAINT PK_docStatus PRIMARY KEY (docId ASC)
    )
```

Comment: Please provide your query

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DDL` -

```
USE tempdb
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.docStatus', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.docStatus
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.docStatus  (
    docId NVARCHAR(256) PRIMARY KEY,
    [count] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    error INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    errorMsg NVARCHAR(1024)
)
```

Your example -

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT docId
        FROM docStatus
        WHERE docId = N'abc'
    )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.docStatus (docId) VALUES (N'abc')
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE docStatus
    SET [count] += 1
    WHERE docId = N'abc'
END
```

`MERGE` statement -

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.docStatus
    WHERE docId = N'abc'
)
MERGE cte t
USING (
    SELECT docId = N'abc'
) s ON s.docId = t.docId
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN
        UPDATE SET t.[count] += 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN
        INSERT (docId, [count])
        VALUES (s.docId, 1);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why that would prevent the violation ? or why it happened in the first place?

Comment: Please provide `DDL` for `documentStatus` with indexes

Comment: I added the DDL, what do you mean by "with indexes"?

Comment: I didn't see any issues in your code. Check about `isolation levels`.   "indexes" - i mean clustered and non-clustered indexes

Comment: Can you explain why you changed my DDL?

Comment: `DEFAULT NULL` unnecessary statement... BTW i propose add `unique index (docId)` and recreate `PK` with identity column... in case when `docId` used in another tables